# CDI bean doesn’t get discovered unless explicitly annotated

Tags: java, jboss, cdi, wildfly, weld

What does it mean when Weld says "unsatisfied dependency for type Foo" when the bean is POJO but, as soon as I add `@Dependent` at the top, everything works ok?
I remember it used to work fine without specifying the scope. I think I broke something.

The specs say:

> A managed bean is implemented by a Java class, which is called its bean class. A top-level Java class is a managed bean if it is defined to be a managed bean by any other Java EE technology specification, such as the JavaServer Faces technology specification, or if it meets all the following conditions.
>
> - It is not a nonstatic inner class.
> - It is a concrete class or is annotated @Decorator.
> - It is not annotated with an EJB component-defining annotation or declared as an EJB bean class in ejb-jar.xml.
> - It has an appropriate constructor. That is, one of the following is the case.
> - The class has a constructor with no parameters.
> - The class declares a constructor annotated @Inject.
>
> **No special declaration, such as an annotation, is required to define a managed bean.**

Comment: From which spec are you quoting? Managed beans or CDI? There's a difference.

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: This is from the CDI spec. Think of Managed Beans as (super) classes with default features and CDI beans as specialized (child class ) version of the Managed Bean super class.  Yes, you do not need any annotation to define a Managed Bean. A valid managed bean enjoys the following services rendered to it by the container - life cycle management, Resource injection and interceptors. CDI builds on top of the managed bean spec and provides additional services - mainly contextual dependency injection. To convert a simple managed bean into a CDI bean, you need to define CDI specific annotations

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like you were used to CDI 1.0 and are now confused by **implicit bean archives** introduced in CDI 1.1.

`beans.xml` is now optional, and implicit bean archives are the default, which means that a class is a bean candidate only if it has a bean defining annotation like `@Dependent`, `@RequestScoped` etc.

Comment: but the specs: A managed bean is implemented by a Java class, which is called its bean class [...] **No special declaration, such as an annotation, is required to define a managed bean**.

Comment: You can turn **implicit bean archives** into **explicit bean archives** eg. by setting `bean-discovery-mode` to `all` in `beans.xml`: https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.1/cdi-spec.html#bean_archive

Comment: The relevant part in the CDI 1.2 spec is here: http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#bean_archive

Comment: @gurghet By default CDI 1.1+ does not require you to create even empty beans.xml (as it was required by v1.0) *but* by default only beans marked with scope annotations are managed by the CDI container.